# Prove $X^tX$, where $X$ is a matrix of full column rank, is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $X$ be a matrix of dimension $n\times k$ where $n>k$,  $\text{rk}(X)=k$ so $X$ is of full column rank. Then how do I prove $X^tX$ is always positive definite, where $X^t$ is transpose of $X$? This is given sortta like a lemma in our lecture slides without proof but would like to have some reasoning behind this. Thank you  for your help!

Answer (score 11):

If $X$ has full column rank, then its columns are linearly independent.
The product $Xv$ with a vector $v$ is a linear combination of the columns of $X$. Therefore,  if $v\neq 0$ ($v$ is not the zero vector) then $y := Xv \neq0$ ($Xv$ is a non-zero vector, since it is a non-trivial linear combination).
Therefore, given any $v\neq 0$ we get
$$ v^tX^t X v = (Xv)^t Xv = y^t y = \sum_i y_i^2 > 0 $$
which is the implication of positive definite.

Comment: So the full rank is important, because otherwise we could find a non-trivial linear combination such that $Xu = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

For any real invertible matrix $X$ we can show that the product $X^tX$ is a positive defined matrix. In fact, let's just take a vector $v$ non-zero. So we can easily see that: $$v^tX^tXv=||Xv||^2>0$$
because since the matrix $X$ is invertible, $Xv\neq 0.$

Comment: but then why does X has to be of full column rank?

Comment: That's because a matrix is invertible if and only if the $\det(A) \neq 0$ and this is true if and only if the matrix has maximum rank.

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci The matrix $X$ isn't (necessarily) square, so the determinant argument doesn't apply. And it's not correct to say that it's invertible either. What _is_ true is that a full column rank matrix is injective, and hence $X\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ implies $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$ by injectivity.